# Plot data point but skip errorbar for invalid error entry

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with three columns containing: an independent variable, x, a dependent variable, y, and the error in y, dy, respectively. To plot my data, I use the command

```
plot "File.txt"  u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars
```

Above a specific x-value, all entries for dy are NaN. This in itself is okay, as the formula used to compute dy breaks down. However, the corresponding data points (x,y), which *are* valid entries, are excluded from the plot.

How can this be avoided, that is, how can I plot the data *with* errorbars up to the point where the dy entries are proper values, and continue to the plot the data *without* errorbars beyond this point?

Of course I can solve it manually by making two different graphs that join up, but I would like to avoid this tedious work.

Here is some fake data to illustrate the point:

```
0,000000 0,000000 3,162278   
1,000000 2,000000 2,828427   
2,000000 4,000000 2,449490   
3,000000 6,000000 2,000000   
4,000000 8,000000 1,414214   
5,000000 10,000000 0,000000   
6,000000 12,000000 NaN   
7,000000 14,000000 NaN   
8,000000 16,000000 NaN   
9,000000 18,000000 NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, also add some model data from your data file. That will enable others to help you much quicker.

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar: Thank you for your suggestion! I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
plot "stats1.dat" u 1:2:($3!=NaN?$3:1/0) w yerrorbars title "My title", '' u 1:(stringcolumn(3) eq "NaN"?$2:1/0) w points pt 1 lc rgb "red" notitle
```

Gives me the following:

[image]

Comment: That looks good! However, I would prefer if the two plots were the same colour and had the same entry in the legend. I guess I can manually specify the correct colour. How can I fix the legend? Can I exclude the 2nd plot from the legend?

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde made one more small change if you like.

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming 5.0 version allows to use a single plot command:

```
plot 'stats1.dat' u 1:2:($3 == NaN ? -1 : $3) w yerrorbars
```

This works, because negative error bars are ignored, and the handling of `NaN` was improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! Maybe I'll try out the development version then :)